# How to post form data and files to server using angular and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a form that has files control which can select multiple images. I want to upload the multiple images to server and data to database. I tried formData:

postNewProduct(vlaue) is called when submit button is pressed:

```
postNewProduct(value) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const files: Array<File> = this.selectedFile;
  for(let i =0; i < files.length; i++){
    formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
  }

  formData.append('productName', value.productName);
  formData.append('productCategory', value.productCategory);
  this.productService.postNewProduct(formData).subscribe(
   message => alert(message));
}
```

onFileSelected(fileInput) is called when images are selected by form controls:

```
onFileSelected(fileInput){
  let images = fileInput.target.files.length;
  if(images < 1 || images > 4){
   alert("please select at image between 1 and 4");
  }else{
   this.selectedFile = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
   console.log(this.selectedFile);
}
}
```

This is my function in service that make calls to api:

```
postNewProduct(newProduct){
  return this.http.post(`/api/product/postproduct`, newProduct);
}
```

this is my function in node backend but there is nothing in request.body and files

```
exports.postProduct = function(request, response) {
  console.log(request.body);
  console.log(request.files);
  productModel.postProduct(request, (message, lastID) => {
    response.json(message, lastID);
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the output if you run ````console.log(request)````?

Comment: its long data, so i print body and files which is empty.

Comment: If they're empty (rather than undefined) and this occurs for all POST requests you make, it sounds like your express middleware may not be configured correctly. If you don't already have it, try adding:

````app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));````
````app.use(bodyParser.json());````

Comment: I have that already. I tried multer in my server side.    
`let multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer();
router.post('/product/postproduct',upload.fields([]),productController.postProduct);`

it shows **MulterError: Unexpected field**